# Actual difference between two lists - not Except

Tags: c#, list, linq

Let's say I have the list

```
var L1 = new List<int>{1,1,2};
var L2 = new List<int>{1};
```

If I do

```
L1.Except(L2)
```

I get `List<int>{2}` - Fair enough.

But is there shorthand to do something like `L1.Minus(L2)` where I would get `List<int>{1,2}`

Basically only remove items as many times as it finds them in L2.

I could write this out - hoping I don't have to.

Comment: Are the lists guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: No and the position shouldn't matter, would expect the {2,1} if L1 was {2,1,1}

Comment: in your thought process is 1,2 and 2,1 the same?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 - In this case yes. Basically if wanted the result to be List<int>{2}, L2 would have to be List<int>{1,1}

Comment: if index matters...how about converting both lists to a tuple(of int, int) where the item1 is the key and item 2 is the value?...then get the difference between those lists?

Comment: What about just `foreach (var item in L2) L1.Remove(item);`? Not the fastest implementation, but should work I think.

Comment: That's what I have now, I was hoping for shorthand -- guess it doesn't exist :-(

Comment: Similar to itsme86's suggestion but a little more "shorthand"... What about `L2.ForEach(x => L1.Remove(x))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to write it yourself, it could look like this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public IEnumerable<T> Minus<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, IEnumerable<T> removal)
    {
        var result = input.ToList();
        foreach (var r in removal) result.Remove(r);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Or possibly like this if you aren't so worried about readability:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public IEnumerable<T> Minus<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, IEnumerable<T> removal)
    {
        var remaining = removal.ToList();
        return input.Where
        (
            a => !remaining.Remove(a)
        );      
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var L1 = new List<int>{1,1,2};
        var L2 = new List<int>{1};
        var L3 = L1.Minus(L2);


        foreach (var l in L3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(l);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

[Working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HHvXaH)

Comment: You don't need the `Contains`... `Remove` will return false if it didn't exist

Answer (score 2):

Minimal example using ForEach and a lambda expression:

```
L2.ForEach(x => L1.Remove(x));
```

Comment: Nitpick - `ForEach` is a method on `List<T>` - it is not a Linq method (and is generally frowned upon)